# AES file encryption in C

Tags: c, gcc, windows-7, aes

I need to compile an AES C source code published from MIT university on Windows 7 platform with GCC. At first I got some "missing file" errors, and now that I solved all of them, I receive a linker error "undefined reference to WinMain16".

I am using CodeBlocks.

What I did:

- copied the aes.c code into new project with codeblocks
- copied needed header files
- compiled the aes.c file

What could possibly be the problem?

Comment: Add the problem description

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259714/undefined-reference-to-winmain16 , seems to be similar to your problem.

Comment: Do you have a `C` file with a `main` in it?

Answer (score 0):

The code you compiled is probably just a library, exporting functions such as `aes_encrypt()`.

To be able to compile it into an executable, you need to tell the library to actually **do** something, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908785/openssl-libcrypto-aes-128-encoding-using-the-key) (just to get the idea; that code probably uses a different library).

Libraries are often supplied with "test files", try checking the MIT library bundle.

Try also looking for AES implementations using that library.

### Update

The [source code you cite](http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/vlcplayer/old/src/ffmpeg/libavutil/aes.c) has a `main()` function defined conditionally, so you need to define `TEST` in order for it to be compiled in, and you need to compile a *console application*, not a GUI Windows application. Windows GUI application require a `WinMain()` function, while console apps use a `main()` function.

Comment: Thanks but the file aes.c contains main function is listed on http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/vlcplayer/old/src/ffmpeg/libavutil/

Comment: OK, now it's much clearer. You appear to be compiling with the wrong project type settings. See updated answer.

Comment: The answer you are commenting. I added an 'Update' section. I also imported that file (and the others .c and .h files), and set Code::Blocks project to 'console application'; I had to remove two assertions and look up Windows `rand()` function, but it did generate an executable.

Comment: Dear Iserni,  I put the AES.c code inside console application and put the common and aes header files inside the project but what is the TEST that I need to compile the AES.c file when I try to build AES.c file it gives me the same error undefined reference to WinMain@16

Comment: If your app requires WinMain, then it is **not** a console application. WinMain is the entry point for a Windows GUI application. As for the TEST, just `#define` TEST in the sources, or set it in the compiler options (for gcc it would be `-DTEST=whatever`; in Code::Blocks it is Project > Build Options > Compiler Settings > #defines).

Comment: Dear Iserni can I have your email, I tried to run it with codeblock as console project but not work?